# Pinnaclecart image slider only in home page

Tags: php, slider, shopping-cart, pinnacle-cart

I added a image slider in new pinnacle cart shopping cart, but shows in all the pages. How will i restrict it only to home page ?

It is using smarty template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variable pinnacle cart were you will get which is the current page(`$current_page`).

```
{if $current_page == "Home"}
   /// Slider code goes here
{/if}
```

And if you want it to be shown in some other page, first see the value of `$current_page` in that particular page, and write conditions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have `home.html` page located at `[cart root]/content/engine/design/templates/pages/site/` so you can add your slider there. Or you can use your template home.html file. If it doesn't exist you can add custom home.html manually because pinnaclecart first look if home.html exist in selected template system and if it doesn't exist then it looks in the folder above. So correct place for your custom home.html in your template is `[cart root]/content/skins/YOURSKIN/templates/pages/site/`.